# Helping getting started using Boost.Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am trying to start unit testing. I am looking at a few C++ frameworks and want to try Boost.Test. The documentation seems very thorough, and it's a bit overwhelming, especially someone new to unit testing. So here's a situation that I want:

Let's say I have 2 classes, `Foo` and `Bar`. I want to write a suite of tests for `Foo` and a suite of tests for `Bar`, preferably in different files. I want to run the tests only if I run the program with a command line parameter. So my `main()` should look something like:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1 && strcmp(argv[0], "-test") == 0)
        run_all_tests();
    else
        return program_main(argc, argv);
}
```

I think `test_foo.cpp` should be something like:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Foo test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( Foo_Test )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Foo1 )
{
    Foo f;
    BOOST_CHECK( f.isValid() );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Foo2 )
{
    Foo f;
    BOOST_CHECK( f.baz() == 5 );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

However, I don't know (1) what the actual command to run the tests is, and (2) how to actually tell the library that I want to run EVERY test.

So, who has experience with Boost.Test? Can someone help in a detailed way? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BOOST.Test is very flexible and you can probably do what you want.  However since you say you are new to unit testing, you should probably follow the standard unit testing structure.

This is to have a separate test project for each project you are unit testing.  Then include the sources and libraries you need to build the test project.

This is cleaner as there are no test logic in your main project that might get run accidentally and it is easy to run the tests as they have their own executable.  This approach also works for testing libraries.  If you follow this structure you will find that most of the BOOST.Test defaults work out of the box and you can just worry about writing you tests and code.

Answer (score 12):

In your `test_foo.cpp`, the macros add test suites and test cases in
to a global list: `master_testsuite`, which is the root of all test
nodes. You just need to compile all the test files like
`test_foo.cpp`, `test_boo.cpp` and a runner, then link them all into on
executable.

The function `unit_test_main` is used to run the tests in `master_testsuite`.

```
boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(
    &init_unit_test,
    argc,
    argv
)
```

Based on the macro you defined before including
`<boost/test/unit_test.h>`, *Boost.Test* may already generate the `main`
function for you.[1] The generated `main` simply invoked
`unit_test_main` with `argc` and `argv` in `main`. It's recommended to
use `unit_test_main` because it can process some console arguments,
like [run test by name](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html).

The first argument of `unit_test_main` is a hook. Depending on
`BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API`, it has different definition.

```
#ifdef BOOST_TEST_ALTERNATIVE_INIT_API
typedef bool        (*init_unit_test_func)();
#else
typedef test_suite* (*init_unit_test_func)( int, char* [] );
#endif
```

You can customize the `master_testsuite` in the hook. In the second
form, the returned value is the new master testsuite.

[1] if `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` and `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` are defined, but
`BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` is not.

Answer (score 5):

You can start the tests from i.e. a menu command, but it's not that simple and sadly not well documented. Even more sad - its not possible to pass the path where the logfile is to be created. I had to add such a commandline option myself. Unfortunately i have not yet submitted it. My code looks like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

#undef main
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

int DoUnitTests()

{
    char *args[] = {"", "--log_level=all", "--auto_start_dbg=yes"};

    bool result = ::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(&init_unit_test_suite, sizeof(args) / sizeof(char*), args);

    MessageDlog("Unittests result: %s", result ? "ERRORS in Unittests" :  "Goooood!");
    return result;
}

#else
int DoUnitTests()

{
}
#endif
```

Comment: What you are talking about? Please be more specific.

Comment: Compiles well all the time with Visual C++... Your link even shows a Warning, not an Error in g++, thus it does compile.

Comment: well ok it *shouldn't compile*. because it's UB.

Answer (score 0):

there's no standalone test runner as in NUnit

you simply build the test cases as a single .exe application (if you are on Windows) and you run it

Comment: I don't understand... how do you just run the program normally (without testing)?

Comment: basically your test_foo.cpp should be build as a single .exe program and link to your library that contains Foo & Bar classes. One of the boost.test header files already defines the main function so I don't think what you proposed is doable.

Comment: Actually there is. It's called console_test_runner. Though it's not relevant to the OP problem since he has a main already.

Comment: they document it as being called boost_test_runner but yes it is called console_test_runner. I am personally trying to work out how to integrate it into objects and be able to just run tests as I wish, rather than it running through a main at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script I wrote which, given a program name and list of classes will generate the makefile, project skeleton and test suite skeletons for each class / module.  It also sets it all up so that the test suite for each class can be run either individually or as part of an all-in-one global suite.

It's call [makeSimple](http://sourceforge.net/projects/makesimple/) and is available on sourceforge.