# Using Boost::Test for parallel code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, mpi

I want to create some tests with boost::unit_test for my parallel (mpi based) C++ codes. I have some basic experiences in using the test framework. For me the main problem, when going to parallel codes, is where to put MPI::Init, such that it is called first. In the test suites I have created there is no main function. Furthermore, does Boost::Test exists correctly (with respect to mpi) when some assertions fail on a subset of the existing ranks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost Test has [fixture support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture.html), which allows you to perform setup/cleanup per test case, test suite, or globally.  Sounds like you should put the call to `MPI::Init` in a global fixture.

```
struct MPIFixture {
    MPIFixture() { MPI::Init(); }
    ~MPIFixture() { /* I bet there's a deinit you should call */ }
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(MPIFixture);
```

If you have trouble working with that, or if you are working in a framework that provides its own `main` function, then you can `#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` before including the Boost headers. Then you can invoke `boost::unit_test::unit_test_main` yourself to run your test suites.

Comment: Fixtures does not work, because MPI::Init needs the command line arguments. Your second proposal solves the problem! For me, also the post http://stackoverflow.com/q/963158/1326595 was useful in this context.

Comment: You can actually access command line arguments in global fixture through the framework::master_test_suite() interface.